# ActionController::UnknownFormat rails 5 controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

**Edit #1**

View for orders/show, I haven't added the invoice yet, but the view should work with or without the link to the invoice, right?

```
<section class="pt-4 px-8 animated">
  <section class="flex flex-wrap justify-between">
    <h3 class="font-normal text-grey-dark mb-4 py-2">Order Information</h3>
    <%= render 'layouts/dashboard/account' %>
  </section>

  <h2 class="text-grey-darkest text-lg no-underline py-4">
    Course: <%= @order.course.title %>
  </h2>

  <section class="py-2">
    <p class="text-grey-darkest text-md pb-4"><%= @order.course.description %></p>

  <p class="text-grey-darkest text-md">
    <b>Course Price:</b>
    £<%= @order.course.price %>
  </p>

  <p class="text-grey-darkest text-md">
    <b>Total Price:</b>
    £<%= @order.amount %>
  </p>
  </section>

  <section class="text-grey-darkest pt-4">
    <h4 class="pb-2">User details</h4>
    <p>Name: <%= current_user.full_name %></p>
    <p>Email: <%= current_user.email %></p>
  </section>
</section>
```

**Original question**

I'm getting an `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error in my controller

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  layout proc { user_signed_in? ? "dashboard" : "application" }

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @orders = Order.includes(:course).all
  end

  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf {
        send_data @order.receipt.render,
        filename: "#{@order.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}-aurameir-courses-receipt.pdf",
        type: "application/pdf",
        disposition: :inline
      }
    end
  end

  def create
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

I am using the https://github.com/excid3/receipts gem which uses `prawn` but I'm unsure as to why the error is there.

Comment: can you please provide the view, which contains a link to show action?

Comment: See edit #1 @IgorDrozdov

Comment: so you're trying to type the url in browser and then you get this error message?

Comment: So I'm going to the order http://localhost:3000/orders/1 and getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `html` format is the default format in `Rails`, you need to provide `pdf` format explicitly in your url or the link builder:

```
localhost:3000/orders/1.pdf
```

Otherwise, it tries to load it as `localhost:3000/orders/1.html`, but you haven't `format.html` handler defined in your controller.

When you implement a link in your application, follow the example in [docs](https://github.com/excid3/receipts#rendering-the-receipt-pdf-in-your-controller):

```
<%= link_to "Download Receipt", charge_path(@charge, format: :pdf) %>
```